# translate MapLibre to openlayer's

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me translate the code below MapLibre to openlayer's?

```
       map.addSource('source', {
        'type': 'vector',
        'tiles': ['url'],
        'minzoom': 6,
        'maxzoom': 14
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Openlayers there are many ways to load a vector layer, one way for a wfs service can look like this

```js
    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
             format : 'wfsFormat',
             loader: 'function'
             strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.*,
    });
    var vectorLayer= new ol.layer.Vector({
             title: 'title',
             visible: true,
             source: vectorSource,
             projection: 'EPSG:4326',
             style: 'function'
    });
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```